# Install cassandra-driver for Python on windows fail with load_ipython_extension import

Tags: python, windows, cassandra

When I follow the instructions "pip install cassandra-driver" on http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html to install the cassandra-driver for Python on a Windows 10 machine, I got the following exception:

ImportError: cannot import name load_ipython_extension

I also tried to do: pip install cassandra-driver --install-option="--no-cython", same exception.

Comment: go to this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pysam-user-group/CQ-S_uWPQsY

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I looked through the page you gave but what piece of information I should find from the page? Thanks.